# new window/tab from href

Tags: javascript, joomla

I have access to a joomla edition but not the source, and I need add a link which must be opened in other window/tab.

I only can change the href field content.

I try with

```
javascript:window.open('http://url/')
```

this work with chrome but not with firefox.

any suggestion?

Comment: Are you sure it's not being blocked as a popup? Are you getting any javascript errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.open), window.open() requires a minimum of two arguments. It also returns the object for the newly opened window, which would cause `[object Window]` to appear in the original window. Returning `undefined` avoids this second issue. This would work:

```
javascript:window.open('http://url/', '_blank');undefined
```

Older code would commonly use the [`void` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/void), which evaluates its only operand and yields an `undefined` result no matter what. So this would also work:

```
javascript:void(window.open('http://url/', '_blank'))
```

In either case, the special window name `_blank` just tells the browser to open a new window or tab. The browser's settings determine the exact behavior because tabbed browsing was introduced after `_blank` was.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a `_blank` [target](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/links.html#attr-hyperlink-target) attribute, which opens the link in a new window/tab (you can't control which one, the browser will pick based on a click event algorithm):

```
<a href="http://blah.com/path" target="_blank">Link</a>
```

Not sure why that wouldn't work in FF using the "javascript:" protocol but the JS, in a regular script tag, would probably work. The [MDN entry on window.open](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.open) might be helpful to read as well.

Comment: I don't have access to the html, I only can change the href field content

Comment: i see, you're trying to change the `href` attribute to something that will open it up in a new tab/window. does the field do sanitization? if not you can break out of the attribute and create a new one with a value like `http://blah.com/path" target="_blank`